# How do C programs pass whitespace arguments to the libc system(3) calls?

Tags: c, arguments, whitespace

When a C program calls `system()` to run a Unix command, I know it's
possible to pass arguments to the command, and according to a
StackOverflow answer (from a very high-rep user), [the `system()` call
uses the shell to execute the
command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757526/5419599).

It surprised me to see `system("ls -lh >/dev/null 2>&1");` as an
example `system()` call for a C program, since it looks like this is
using the same whitespace delimited "words" as the shell uses
interactively.

From my standpoint as a sysadmin, I'd like to understand what the
provisos and pitfalls are when a `system()` call is going to be executed
from within a C program on some files or commands on my system.
Passing whitespace-containing filenames into a *shell script* is
[very issue-prone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943);
are there similar issues when a C program is calling a command?

Or to make the point even blunter (though less exact): Is a C program
written by a novice just as likely to break on whitespace-containing
filenames as a shell script?

Comment: It just runs `sh -c '...'`.

Comment: You're confusing calls to function "system()" and "system calls", which are functions implemented in the kernel and callable from userland (through a wrapper in the standard library). The function "system()" is implemented in the C standard library and issues the system call "execve".

Comment: (1) If you know that the `system()` function uses the shell to execute the command, why are you surprised that it uses shell syntax? (2) As a sysadmin, you should try to minimize the use of the `system()` function in programs on your system — don't use it, and discourage others from using it — especially if the program runs in a privileged context and/or builds its command string dynamically; ***especially*** if it builds its command string from user-supplied input. If you must use it, put a ***lot*** of thought and effort into validating the user input, to prevent code-injection-type attacks.

Comment: @lgeorget, that is precisely what I was confusing: `system()` and `execve()`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing to do in C source here, the string you pass to *system()* was run in shell context. The shell will parse that string, your C program doesn't.

---

If you look at [system() function prototype](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int system(const char *command);
```

The argument passed to `system()` is a string. It has nothing to do with whitespaces characters in string, it gets a string and passes that string to other system call. The same as you did:

```
sh -c 'ls -l'
```

Here *system()* use [execve()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html):

```
$ cat <<\CODE | gcc -xc -
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  system("ls -l");
  return 0;
}
CODE

$ strace -fe execve ./a.out
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
Process 16281 attached
[pid 16281] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "ls -l"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
Process 16282 attached
[pid 16282] execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "-l"], [/* 64 vars */]) = 0
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

The `system()` function is a C library call that runs a shell to start an other program, and waits for its result. It is useful for the common need of wanting to run an external command to check if some external condition is satisfied. It does indeed use the shell to start the external command.

It is, not a system call. A system call is a direct request to the kernel; things like 'give me more memory', 'open a file' and 'write this stuff to a file descriptor' are. The `system()` function is implemented in terms of (at least) three system calls:

1. `fork()`, to spawn off a child process.
2. One of the `exec()` family, called by the child, to *replace* that child process by another executable
3. `wait()`, called by the parent, to wait for the child process to finish and read its exit state.

The `exec()` call starts the process *without* involving any shell, and therefore no whitespace expansion occurs. It is, in theory, possible to bypass the `system()` function, and then you wouldn't have whitespace issues. That's a lot of work, though, and not usually worth it, because there's a lot *more* that can go wrong there.

Which brings me to my point: if you're worried about novice people dealing with shell scripts, you shouldn't let them deal with C compilers. It is possible to do a lot more wrong in C than in shell...

Answer (score 1):

If a C program uses `system()` to invoke another program, it must create a command to be parsed by the shell (specifically, `/bin/sh`).

The implementation of `system(const char *command)` will normally end up calling something like `execl('/bin/sh', 'sh', '-c', command, (char*)NULL)` in the child process (and the `execl` library function will end up calling `execve` system call).