# query usb flash drive volume label programmatically

Tags: c, linux

My objective is to determine the name of a mounted USB flash drive programmatically in linux using C.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with _the name of detected USB flash drive_?

Comment: I mean the display name, the name of the device that I specify when I format it

Comment: You do not format a disk but rather a partition (aka volume). The name you assign to it after formatting is called a *volume label*. To query the volume label you do not use any `USB` API but rather file system API.

Comment: you can use the command: `lsusb -v  -t` to determine where the device is mounted,  Then pass that address as a parameter to your program

Answer (score 0):

think the USB stick is registered as `/dev/sdb` (you can determine which is the USB stick in `/dev` using `sudo fdisk -l` or `dmesg` with `tail` and `grep`)

if you want to get the **label** of the USB stick you can use `sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 -s ::`  and then extract the label using `grep`, `awk` or `sed`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive

if you want to get the **UUID** you can use `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`

-> **https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67464/how-to-get-uuid-for-a-usb-drive** <-

https://serverfault.com/questions/3132/how-do-i-find-the-uuid-of-a-filesystem

See this [Execute a Linux command in the c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757512/execute-a-linux-command-in-the-c-program) and [how to execute a command as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822599/how-to-execute-a-command-as-root) for executing linux commands like `blkid` in C